# How to pass the output of command as the input of another?

Tags: php, symfony, stdin, symfony-console

I'm using a Symfony console application and trying to passed the output of phpstan as the input of my console command:

```sh
vendor/bin/phpstan analyse | bin/wte analyse
```

Currently the commands run as expected, but how can I pass the output of phpstan into the `bin/wte analyse` command?

```php
// AnalyseCommand.php 
final class AnalyseCommand extends Command
{
    public const NAME = 'analyse';

    /**
     * @var SymfonyStyle
     */
    private $symfonyStyle;

    public function __construct(SymfonyStyle $symfonyStyle)
    {
        $this->symfonyStyle = $symfonyStyle;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        // Get phpstan output in here. 

        return ShellCode::SUCCESS;
    }

    protected function configure(): void
    {
        $this->setName(self::NAME);
        $this->setDescription('Find an error');

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Symfony Console doesn't have any feature dealing with standard input. But it's not needed, because you are still on PHP and can use any [native features](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php).

```php
public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
{
    $stdin = '';

    while (!feof(STDIN)) {
       $stdin .= fread(STDIN, 1024);
    } 
    
    // do what you need with $stdin
}
```